# Wordpress - problems with dynamic js/css and SSL

Tags: php, javascript, css, wordpress

(Related to another question in this forum, thought I'd try rephrasing and putting in the WordPress area...)

Trying to load WordPress site "domain.com" over SSL.  Certificate is installed correctly, all links to graphics and other files are properly converted to urls with https except I get these errors:

```
[blocked] The page at https://domain.com/ ran insecure content from http://domain.com/?dynamic=css.

[blocked] The page at https://domain.com/ ran insecure content from http://domain.com/?dynamic=js.
```

The pertinent HTML is as follows:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>/?dynamic=css" />
```

and

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>/?dynamic=js"></script>
```

So it looks like I have a snag in loading dynamically-generated css or js over SSL.  Debian/Apache2.  Anyone know how to fix it?  Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't seen any browser totally barf on insecure content, but IE will show a warning.

The solution is for *every* resource to load over SSL if HTTPS is specified.

One nifty protocol-agnostic technique is to simply write `//example.com` instead of `https://example.com` or `http://example.com`. The protocol will be determined by whatever is currently in use.

So if you are on `http://example.com/checkout/`, then resources will use `http://example.com` as the base. If the connection is secure, resources will automagically point to `https://example.com` without any conditional code.

In the Wordpress admin panel, you can specify the URL which is returned by `bloginfo('url')`.

Edit: there is a way to do this in the HTML directly. Change `bloginfo('url');` to `str_replace('http:', '', bloginfo('url'));`

Comment: So are you saying that I can replace, for example:

`href="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>/?dynamic=css"` with
href="//domain.com?dynamic=css"
?

Comment: What I'm saying is that `bloginfo('url')` is what's screwing you at this point. It's returning an insecure URL. You'll have to change its output in the admin panel.

Comment: I'm only establishing a secure connection for a checkout page.  Wouldn't redefining bloginfo('url') make all pages load over SSL?

Comment: No, not by using the syntax described in my answer.

Comment: `bloginfo('url')` uses `home_url`, which is SSL aware

Comment: Sorry to be a dunce, but I'm afraid I'm about to do something that's going to lock me out of a working site.  Are you referring to the "Wordpress address" and "Site address" fields that can be defined under Settings->General Settings?

Comment: Well the link to the js and css content now starts with https...thank you...but the error still remains.  There's nothing but styling in the css file, so I have no idea what the H is going on.

Answer (score 0):

There is a plugin you can use to force assets to be fetched (per page) via SSL (https) here: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wordpress-https/

Comment: Yes, I'm using that extension :-)

Comment: one of your scripts or css files is still referencing a hard-coded http perhaps?

Comment: I've had it happen before where using a url param on the end of my file causes this, once I removed it, it worked. I think the query string param constitutes a different page load or something. What is generating your files? You could try linking that to a static file for a sec, just to see if that does it. Worth a shot.